# Not able to understand the output of this C pointer to arraycode

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Here is code about the array to pointer.
The problem is that I don't understand the output.
According to what I have studied `*p` means value at address p is containing and `*(*p)`  value at address at (value at address p containing)
then why the output is different.

Code:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 #include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
static int a[ ] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 } ;
int *p[ ] = { a, a + 1, a + 2, a + 3, a + 4 } ;
printf ( "\n%u %u %d", p, *p, * ( *p ) ) ;
}
```

and output is

```
3545106368 6293840 0
```

Please help me to understand this output. Keep it simple and easy for me.

Comment: You need to read a good book, not a question here..

Comment: You invoke undefined behaviour. `%u` is not the correct conversion specifier for a pointer. And `p` is not a pointer, but an array. Please understand this is not a tutoring site. follow @SouravGhosh s advice and look up the basics in your prefered C book (note: use at least one that covers C99, better standard C, i.e. C11).

Comment: It's typically a good case to use debugger to observe directly variables and there contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In memory your arrays looks something like this:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| a[0] | a[1] | a[2] | a[3] | a[4] |
+------+------+------+------+------+
 ^      ^      ^      ^      ^
 |      |      |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+------+
| p[0] | p[1] | p[2] | p[3] | p[4] |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I.e. each element of `p` is pointing to the corresponding element in `a`.

Then you have to learn that when using an array, it decays to a pointer to its first element, i.e. the expression `p` is the same as `&p[0]`. So when you are printing out `p` then you are printing out the address of the first element of the array `p`.

When you dereference the pointer given by `p`, then you are effectively doing `*&p[0]`. The dereference and address-of operators cancel each other out, so when you print `*p` you are printing `p[0]` which is the value of the first element in the array `p`.

That element, `p[0]`, is in turn a pointer to `a[0]`. So when you dereference that pointer (in `**p`, which is the same as `*p[0]`) then you get the value of `a[0]`.

---

Also, for any array *or* pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is the same as `*(p + i)`. From that follows that `p[0]` is the same as `*(p + 0)` which is the same as `*(p)`  which is the same as `*p`.

From that follows the logic that `p` and `&p[0]` are the same.

And to really screw you around, due to the [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of addition, the expression `*(p + i)` is the same as `*(i + p)` which leads to the peculiar but valid expression `i[p]`.

Last but not least, when printing a pointer with `printf`, you should really be using the `"%p"` format. It takes a `void*` as argument, and you also need to cast the pointers for the program to be valid. So your `printf` call should look like

```
printf ( "%p %p %d\n", (void *) p, (void *) *p, **p ) ;
```

See e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for more information.

Comment: thanks for it .It really clear my concept about array and pointer and also  thanks for keeping it simple really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
int *p[ ]
```

here `p` is an array containing pointers to integer.

```
 0  1   2   3   4
 |  |   |   |   |
 a a+1 a+2 a+3 a+4   => p

 printf ( "\n%u %u %d", p, *p, * ( *p ) ) ;
```

`p` is pointer to first element of `p` which is `a`(which is a pointer to `0`)

`*p` is value at `p` which is `a` which is an address that points to `0`.

`*(*p)` is like `*a` which give s `0`.

Also the correct specifier for an address is `*p` and not `*u`.